# TypeError at /export_to_xls/ unorderable types: str() < int()

Tags: python, django

views

```
def export_to_xls(request):
    obitos = Obito.objects.all()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-    officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={date}-movies.xlsx'.format(date=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),)

    workbook = Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.active
    worksheet.titulo = "teste-Obitos"

    columns = [
    'nome_obito',
    'idade_obito',
  ]
    row_num = 1

    for col_nome, col_idade in enumerate(columns, 1):
     cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_idade)
     cell.value = col_idade

    for obito in obitos:
     row_num += 1
     row = [
        obito.nome_obito,
        obito.col_idade
     ]
     for col_num, cell_value in enumerate(row, 1):
        cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
        cell.value = cell_value
    workbook.save(response)
    return response
```

To com esse problema na geração do xls! Alguma sugestão? Obrigado.

Comment: Olá @sedarky evite colocar imagens em suas perguntas, coloque a mensagem do erro em Amostra de Código no campo "{ }" para podermos ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por favor edite sua pergunta:

- A identação do código está errada;
- O erro não está com o *traceback* completo, além disso parte do *traceback* está em forma de imagem, onde deveria ser texto puro;
- O erro está no título, onde deveria ser uma pergunta

RESPOSTA:

`col_idade` é uma `str` (vem da lista `columns` que só possui `str`s) mas você está passando ela para o parâmetro `columns=` do método `cell()`. Esse parâmetro deve receber um número inteiro (o número da coluna) e não um nome.

Tente passar a posição atual da lista:

```
for col_posicao, col_titulo in enumerate(columns, 1):
    cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_posicao)
    cell.value = col_titulo
```

Comment: Resolvido! Era isso mesmo nosklo! Obrigado.

Comment: @sedarky ainda não está resolvido, falta consertar a pergunta e marcar a resposta como aceita